# Jumping into C++: Tic Tac Toe game [using enum]

Tags: c++

First and foremost, I ask that anyone who is replying consider these factors. Currently I have very-low knowledge in arrays and enumerations, most of the basics are understood such as what you will see below. I have been trying to figure this problem out for 3 days and now I'm asking for help before I keep burning myself out every 45mins-1hr.

**Problem: Write a two-player tic-tac-toe game, allowing two humans to play against each other; use
enums when possible to represent the values of the board**

````
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

bool tie = false;
std::string p1, p2;
enum turnbased{token1, token2, empty};
char space[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
int row;
int column;
int token;

void board() //producing the required space[][] coordinates to empty squares
{
    std::cout << "     |    |    \n";
    std::cout <<"  "<<space[0][0]<<"  | "<<space[0][1]<<"  | "<<space[0][2]<<" \n";
    std::cout << " ____|____|____\n";
    std::cout <<"  "<<space[1][0]<<"  | "<<space[1][1]<<"  | "<<space[1][2]<<" \n";
    std::cout << " ____|____|____\n";
    std::cout << "     |    |    \n";
    std::cout <<"  "<<space[2][0]<<"   | "<<space[2][1]<<"    | "<<space[2][2]<<" \n";
    std::cout << "     |    |    \n";
}

void playerswitch()
{
    turnbased assignto = token1; //initializing enum type to define token1 for turns to occur
    int token = empty; //declaring token to equivalate to enum variable{empty} in position()

    if(assignto)
    {
        std::cout << p1 << " choose slot for - " << token1;

        assignto = token2;
    }
    else(assignto == token2);
    {
        std::cout << p2 << " choose slot for - " << token2;

        assignto;
    }
    std::cin >> token;
}

void position()
{

        if(empty == 1) // positioning array space
        {
            row = 0;
            column = 0;
        }
        else if(empty == 2)
        {
            row = 0;
            column = 1;
        }
        else if(empty == 3)
        {
            row = 0;
            column = 2;
        }
        else if(empty == 4)
        {
            row = 1;
            column = 0;
        }
        else if(empty == 5)
        {
            row = 1;
            column = 1;
        }
        else if(empty == 6)
        {
            row = 1;
            column = 2;
        }
        else if(empty == 7)
        {
            row = 2;
            column = 0;
        }
        else if(empty == 7)
        {
            row = 2;
            column = 1;
        }
        else if(empty == 8)
        {
            row = 2;
            column = 2;
        }
        else(empty < 1 || empty > 9);
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid!!!" << std::endl;
        }
    //token check and execution
    if(token1 && space[row][column] != token1 && space[row][column] != token2)
    {
        space[row][column] = token1;
        token2;
    }
    else if(token2 && space[row][column] != token1 && space[row][column] != token2)
    {
        space[row][column] = token2;
        token1;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Invalid space!" << std::endl;
        position();
    }
    playerswitch();
    board();
}

//win check
bool results()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {   //checks horizontally and vertically
        if(space[i][0] == space[i][1] && space[i][0] == space[i][2] || space[0][i] == space[1][i] && space[0][i] == space[2][i])
        return true;
        //checks diagonally
        if(space[0][0] == space[1][1] && space[1][1] == space[2][2] || space[0][2] == space[1][1] && space[1][1] == space[2][0])
        return true;

        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(space[i][j] != token1 && space[i][j] != token2)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    tie = true;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the name of the first player: \n";
    getline(std::cin, p1);
    std::cout << p1 << " is player1 so he/she will play first \n";
    std::cout << "Enter the name of the second player: \n";
    getline(std::cin, p2);
    std::cout << p2 << " is player2 so he/she will play second \n";

    while(!results())
    {
        board();
        playerswitch();
        position();
        results();
    }
    if(token1 && tie)
    {
        std::cout << p2 << " wins!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(token2 && tie)
    {
        std::cout << p1 << " wins!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "It's a draw!" << std::endl;
    }

}```
````

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please be more specific than "this problem".

Comment: You will have multiple build errors. I recommend you take a couple of steps back, refresh some text-books and do their simpler exercises about things like `if` and `else` and other things.

Comment: You need to study the syntax of conditionals in more detail. In particular, the `else` does not want a condition, and `else (assignto == token2);` is equivalent to `else { assignto == token2; }`, which has no effect at all. (Enable more warnings in your compiler and take them seriously.)

Comment: Looks like a classic example of writing more code than you can handle. When you are a beginner you cannot write three lines of code without introducing a bug. So if you write thirty lines of code you can easily have ten bugs. It's impossible to make progress when you are dealing with that many errors. The answer is to write only a few lines of code, make sure those lines are working before writing a few more. Write your code like that and (hopefully) you will only ever be dealing with one bug at a time.

Comment: You have taken the wrong approach (certainly not the first beginner to do that). Put that code to one side, start again using the approach I described above. It is a much more efficient way to write code.

Comment: @UnholySheep the question is the problem in bold letters

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did all of that and went back multiple times to broaden perception

Comment: @molbdnilo I mean when you are researching online and have the C++ programming language special edition book, along with a full on tutorial for jumping into c++. I don't know much else I can pick up. Any recommendations?

Comment: @john My code isn't giving me any bugs. I always fix them when it pops up, and at times, the compiler will output some bugs depending on what I've changed.

Comment: That is not a question. It is an assignment statement

Comment: @Japer Well that's another newbie misconception, equating bugs with compiler errors. In programming the real problems only start when you have fixed the compiler errors. But you'll learn, one way or another. My advice is sincerely meant, you are taking the wrong approach, which is why you are finding it so difficult.

Comment: @john I can believe it. Are their any questions you recommend for me to ask myself?

Comment: @UnholySheep you realize I never called the problem a question. You did.

Comment: Well, this website is a "question and answer" site, so your post does not fit the rules if you don't have an actual question

Comment: @UnholySheep please stop trying to combat a beginner. I said I was asking for help, which means any help anyone would give me pertaining to the above code. If I had specifics that I knew of, I'd have asked.

Comment: @Japer I would say you should ask yourself 'what piece of the overall program can I separate out, code as an independent function and then test in isolation?' Ask that question, code that function, test that function and then move on by asking the same question again for the rest of the program. This is essentially what bitmask says in his answer. I would just emphasise the iterative nature of this process,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wont fix your code, but I will help you structure it so you can figure it and future problems out yourself.

First, get rid of all global variables. This is important because the way to reason about code is to look at individual parts in isolation. This is the only, the **ONLY**, way writing code scales.

To do this, define an interface and a clear job for each of your functions. Maybe add structs to keep data together that belongs together.

After you have changed the functions to work only on their input arguments (look up how functions receive arguments and return values), you can test each function on its own. Make sure your function to read in input works. Make sure your function to manipulate the playing field works. Do all this *before* you plug them together. This is called unit testing.

Once you are convinced, that regardless the data that your function receives it always does a proper job, plug them together and see if the result works. If it doesn't, your first goal is to figure out *which* function is broken. Go back to unit testing with new test inputs.

Rinse and repeat until your program works correctly.

Comment: Nice answer. 'I don't understand how function parameters and return values work so I'm going to use globals' is very common for beginners. As is the variation 'I don't understand the value of design so I'm going to put most of my data in globals'.